# Set a variable for the audiofile in AVAudioPlayer / Swift

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

I have a AVAudioPlayer and i would like playing a song in function of a variable « circuit ». variable will have the name of a song, saved on a root of the app.

```
class MonumentViewController: UIViewController {

    var circuit:String!

var BackgroundAudio = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL:NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("dguetta", ofType: "mp3")!), error: nil)
```

I try this code just below, but i’ve got the following error message :  `'MonumentViewController.Type'does not have a member named 'circuit'`

```
var BackgroundAudio = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL:NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(circuit, ofType: "mp3")!), error: nil)
```

Any help will be appreciated

Edit :

I've dealt with that a struct ()

```
 struct MyVariables {


        static var pisteaudio = "dguetta"
        static var BackgroundAudio = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL:NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(pisteaudio, ofType: "mp3")!), error: nil)
    }
```

And i add "MyVariables." for variables.

Comment: any explanation for this bad rating ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot initialize an instance property that is reliant on an other property this way, especially when self is not yet created.

Your `BackgroundAudio` is dependent on the `circuit` variable, with which you create an instance of an `AVAudioPlayer` and it itself is not initialized yet.

Instead, here is an example of how you can create an `AVAudioPlayer` and then set it to play your sound file:

```
class MonumentViewController: UIViewController 
{
    var circuit : String!
    var BackgroundAudio = AVAudioPlayer()

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        prepareAudioPlayer()
    }

    func prepareAudioPlayer()
    {
        circuit = "chopin-tristesse-in-e-major"
        //it is of good practice to always make use of error, instead of passing nil to the parameter
        var error : NSError?

        if let BackgroundAudio = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL:NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(circuit, ofType: "mp3")!), error:&error)
        {
            if(error != nil)
            {
                print("Error has occurred")
            }
            else
            {
                BackgroundAudio.prepareToPlay()
                BackgroundAudio.play()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As a side note, please name your variable beginning with a lower-case and apply the camel case convention:

I.e.,

```
var thisIsMyString : String! 

var backgroundAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: very useful and correct. I dealt with my issue thanks to  a struct ()